# SSH host: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, local

I am trying to do SSH localforward port setting in VI config file, so that I can connect [Hive](https://hivemc.com) server to do some [R programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)).

Steps followed:

1. In shell, I configured below in VI config file:

```
Host bdp-*
UserName a6000

Host bdp-prod
HostName pdl001.na.abc.com
LocalForward 10000:pdl002.na.abc.com:10000
```

2. When I do

```
ssh bdp-prod
```

I get this error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname bdp-prod: Name or service not known

I saw couple of similar issues posted here and viewed [some blogs related to this setting](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/) but couldn’t figure out what is wrong:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname hnname: Name or service not known

OS-windows, ssh version is 4.1. bdp-prod is alias name for the hostname in config file.

Comment: Following up to @JakeGould, the hostname that needs to be resolvable on **your** computer is `pdl001.na.abc.com`.  Regardless, unless you have a very different version of `ssh`, the `UserName` directive is not valid; should be just `User`.  So, the question remains, what OS **and** what version of `ssh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the config file created at incorrect location. I now created configuration using

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
```

with same content as mentioned in question and able to have local port forward work. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score -2):

```
nscd --invalidate=hosts
```

worked for me.

Comment: Some detail on what this does and why you need to do it would make this a good answer.